# json returning with my header data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, coldfusion

HI below is the json data returning from cfc.i used this example and when i trid to implement it working but adding to my working site gives below json data any ideas how to return only json data instead of extra site data.
i used example from here.
[CFC JSON Output - Issue with displaying query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063633/cfc-json-output-issue-with-displaying-query-results)

Welcome to mysite
Logged in as: myname

```
* Home
* Add 
* Edit/Update 
* Delete 


{"ROWCOUNT":1,"COLUMNS":["ID","FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME"],"DATA":{"ID":["1234"],"FIRST_NAME":["xxx"],"LAST_NAME":["yyy"]}}
```

Comment: Do you have something in Application.cfc's onRequest?  Or are you using any sort of framework?

Answer (score 3):

Add cfcontent reset="true" just before you return the JSON.

Comment: There is also the <cfcontent type="application/json" />